# Git: Plumbing for porcelain?

Tags: git, scripting

Suppose I've written a substantial script to do git-stuff (in support of a local work flow). As a first cut, I've used the same commands I use every day, but these are of course "porcelain," and there are many 
[warnings](http://schacon.github.io/git/git.html#_low_level_commands_plumbing)
against
[scripting](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain)
in "porcelain"; that's what "plumbing" is for.

OK, I'm game. Only, how do I determine which of my "porcelain" should be translated into "plumbing," and where do I learn what "plumbing" adds up to my "porcelain"?

The best advice I've found is the 
[Git Internals chapter of The Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain), but that is a very deep yet very cursory discussion of a very limited subset of the very large problem space (it seems to end with a tacit challenge: "See? I **told** you this was too hard for mortals!").

Just to be concrete, I use these commands:

```
git fetch -q
git co -q "$VENDORBRANCH"
git pull -q
git co -q "$TARGETBRANCH"
git pull -q
git co -q -b "$MERGEBRANCH"
git diff --stat ..."$VENDORBRANCH"
git diff ..."$VENDORBRANCH"
git merge -m"Merging $VENDORBRANCH" -q "$VENDORBRANCH"
git commit -m"Bringing $TARGETBRANCH into $MERGEBRANCH."
git push -q --set-upstream origin "$MERGEBRANCH"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the warning about scripting is about not trusting git to use any specific output format; Git really cannot change what e.g. `pull` or `merge` logically do, so the above should be safe. Basically if you start parsing the output of any given command, it should be part of plumbing to be safe.

However, I'd definitely suggest putting `set -e` at the start of your script to automatically abort running additional commands if one fails.

Answer (score 0):

It at least looks like you're using each of the commands here to do just what it was built for. There's nothing wrong with that. When you find yourself undoing or just bearing unwanted effects, that's the "you're doing it wrong" symptom. [Here's an example of what I mean, I'm sure there are lots of other examples all over SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057670/git-how-do-i-squash-changes-to-ignored-files-without-losing-those-changes).

Comment: So you think I can ignore the risk that, say, `git diff --stat` might someday be re-named `git diff --summary`? Or the "--set-upstream" option to push be deprecated? I might be less timid about that, but I happened upon some discussion, recently, suggesting that the "--porcelain" switch on several porcelain commands is really badly named, and proposing renaming the switch in some future version. (Sorry, can't put my finger on the link just now.)

Comment: Not "ignore the risk" really, more of, since you're using those commands for their intended purposes the odds that some later change will break what you're depending on drop sharply. I'll go out on a limb and say no one would dare break `diff --stat`, that's just too fundamental.  They might switch to more convenient or informative output format, because those commands' output isn't intended for script consumption, but you also don't depend on that. Nothing's safe against a headstrong dev nobody's got the sand to face down, that kind of change will either happen or it won't. No point worrying.